# Start thin as non-root in bundle exec context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, thin

I need to start thin aus user - not as root. So I changed the whole environment to run the server in user-mode. Problem is, that I wanna start different thin's for different apps. But I'ld love to use bundle exec instead of gemsets - because I don't wanna update the gemsets all the time when updating the app.

So how could I change the init.d - script to start thin in bundler environment?

I tried this:

```
su - rubyuser -c "bundle exec /var/www/myapp/deploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin start -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml"
```

but it ends up in "Could not locate Gemfile"